# Looking for JS that shows/hides images in div (see example in description)

Tags: javascript

http://www.ppowgallery.com/artists.php has an example of what I want. I want to load a bunch of images and have them appear when you roll over an item in a list or another text link.

Can somebody direct me to a good example? I don't even know what you'd call this effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link mentioned by you in the question itself is an example. Why dont you use it? Basically it creates all the divs with hidden effect and shows them onmouseover of the corresponding links.

Comment: I guess I should. I was just wondering if there was anything prettier out there. Thanks.